# Convert s3 video files resolution and store it back to s3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, django-rest-framework

I want to convert s3 bucket video file resolutions to other resolutions and store it back to s3.
I know we can use ffmpeg locally to change the resolution.
Can we use ffmpeg to convert s3 files and store it back using Django?

I am puzzled as from where to start and what should be the process.
Whether I should have the video file from s3 bucket in buffer and then convert it using ffmpeg and then upload it back to s3.
Or is there anyway to do it directly without having to keep it in buffer.

Comment: Mediaconvert or Elastictranscoder solution are offered by AWS and they take input from S3 and save to S3 Which would be easy but comes with the cost.

Comment: [Amazon Elastic Transcoder - Media & Video Transcoding in the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/details/)

Answer (score 3):

You can break the problem into 3 parts:

- Get the file from s3: use boto3 & the AWS APIs to download the file
- Convert the file locally: ffmpeg has got you covered here. It'll generate a new file
- Upload the file back to s3: use boto3 again

This is fairly simple and robust for a script.

Now if you want to optimize you can try using something like `s3fs` to mount your s3 bucket to local & do the conversion

Comment: Is there any possible way to do it?
Without downloading the file locally.

Comment: ffmpeg works on local files only - you can point it to a file url in S3 but it will still download it before making changes. If you absolutely want to avoid downloading to your machine, you can create an EC2 instance, download the files to that, convert them there, and then download the converted files via scp.